# Confused about tensorflow timeline

Tags: tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPj5Q.png)

I think /device:GPU:0 and /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 denote the same thing, but why their timelines are different? For example, the blue Conv2d of /device:GPU:0 is later than /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0. Can somebody explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`stream:all` indicates the computation itself happening. `/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0` are just the requests being made to enqueue kernels.

See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-244251867